# Check for changes in a file

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have a wordpress site that is being relentlessly hacked. I have backups so can restore the site back to normal no problem. 
Whay I am trying to do is find out specifically which files are being hacked so I can cross reference that info with the log files...
My thought was to create a csv file with file checksums after a clean backup and then compare the files against the csv file once the site was hacked.

I am on shared hosting so can't use node.js

This is what I have so far, it's comparing the files that I am struggling with.

**First create the CSV file with known clean files....**

```
$fp = fopen('/var/sites/p/xxxx.co.uk/public_html/files/sitefiles.csv', 'wb');

$csv_output = "";

$path = realpath('/var/sites/p/xxx.co.uk/public_html/');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
  {
        //echo "$filename</br>";
        $csv_output .= '' . $filename . ',' . $mymd5 = md5($filename) . '';
        $csv_output .= "\n";
  }

fwrite($fp, $csv_output);

fclose($fp);
```

**and then read the files again once hacked to make a comparison.**

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("/var/sites/p/xxxx.co.uk/public_html/files/sitefiles.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: There are already plugins out there that can do this for you. For example, WP Cerber does tell you if the checksum of a file has changed or not. Unless you're doing this to learn, I'd install the plugin and save myself some time.

Comment: I have tried WP Cerber and Wordfence and neither have indicated any file changes or malicious code. The site is being hacked on a weekly basis with redirects when clicking on menu items.

Comment: I'd consider reaching out to the hosting provider here. Maybe the problem isn't your site but the server itself (or another site in the server) being infected.

Comment: I have done that too. They scanned my site from their end but didn't find anything. They didn't offer any other solutions when I asked how to stop the recurrences or to find out how they are accessing my site. Don't really want to change hosting unless I know they are at fault.

Comment: As @cabrerahector pointed out, this may not even be your site being directly hacked, but because of the shared hosting environment, you could be getting hit because of others' security vulnerabilities. What types of files are getting hacked that you notice?

Comment: I haven't as yet been able to locate exactly which files have been hacked, hence the question on here. The redirect happens when a menu item is clicked and the user gets redirected to another site.

Comment: cleaning your site is not only about re-installing the files, need to also check users, DB, other services etc..https://stackoverflow.com/a/32492427/1244126

Comment: Thats a very helpful link - thanks