# What is hacked by mr.green on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I just installed my wordpress on a digital ocean droplet.

But when I visit my URL, it shows this...[image]

I even tried deleting the wordpress folder, and redownload, it says the same. What do i do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Site Keeps Getting Hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489870/wordpress-site-keeps-getting-hacked)

Answer (score 1):

Hacked by MR.GREEN is the title of your site, which is in the database under wp_options (Wp-admin -> settings)so it would not be fixed by replacing the core files.

Because he might have left malicious code on the server, you'll need to completely reinstall; make sure to add some security plugins like wordfence and configure a firewall.

PS -  My name has 'e' so its not me.

Answer (score 0):

If you [google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=mr%20green%20wordpress) it, there is a lot of wordpress sites with this strange message in the headers. Most of them are just a default installation.

It's almost impossible to know if this is the real problem (could be a joke, a XSS attack, another one, or nothing) but there are something that you can do:

> 1) Check if your WP version and plugins are at date.
>
> 2) If you just installed WP using a service of your hosting, you must
>   to send a ticket to them.
>
> 3) Third Party plugins and themes may be vulnerable, avoid use them if
>   you are not sure what they do.

Comment: Yes I saw. Its strange how there is almost nothing about this topic though. Thankfully I am in early stages of development, I got a new droplet from digital ocean and reinstalled my server.