# Remove Malware wp-cleansong

Tags: wordpress, malware

Good morning, I suddenly found administrator users on my wordpress site and a plugin called wp-cleansong that I never installed. The site redirects when I browse. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Site Keeps Getting Hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489870/wordpress-site-keeps-getting-hacked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i leave you details about this hack:

**Vulnerable plugin:** litespeed-cache (CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:C/C:L/I:L/A:N)

Affected Version <= 5.7
Patched Version 5.7.0.1

You can fast check at wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/readme.txt

**Symptoms:**

Creation of admin users
Redirects generated by js hooked in wp_head via function clean_header() function
Infected core files like wp-blog-header.php
**Execution:**

Attackers can inject arbitrary web scripts into pages that will run when an administrator logs in for the first time in wp-admin. The plugin will in fact be created on exactly the same date and time as login as you can see from the access.log Plane.php point ot a base64 url =base64_decode("aHR0cHM6Ly9kbnMuc3RhcnRzZXJ2aWNlZm91bmRzLmNvbS9zZXJ2aWNlL2YucGhw"); point to hxxps://dns[.]startserv**founds[.]com/service/f.php (blacklisted url)

**Sources :**

https://www.wordfence.com/threat-intel/vulnerabilities/wordpress-plugins/litespeed-cache/litespeed-cache-57-reflected-cross-site-scripting-via-nameservers-and-msg

https://www.risorsainformatica.com/rimozione-malware-sito-wordpress/

Malware removal performed on over 1500 websites, of which 30 with this specific attack.

**Notes:**
First detected on February 27, 2024

**Prevention:**
Update to latest version Litespeed cache plugin

HTTP(S) monitoring for /plugins/wp-cleansong/plane.php

Block using htaccess the requests to song and song1

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} song1 [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} song2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]

Also you can block plane.php , wp-cleansong.php and song.php